# Copies of Hidden Sheets in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this fragment of code that make a copy of each Sheet in the document. I don't know if it makes copies of Hidden Sheets, the _temp copy of the hidden sheets do not appear in the interface but i suppose they are also hidden. In case it does the copies, how could I modify the code to not copy hidden sheets? I have a lot of hidden sh in my document and it could save time and avoid crashes.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet) {
  var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
  var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
  src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
  return dstSheet;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you first check if it actually does copy hidden sheets? I suppose there is *some* way to see them or otherwise know of their existence, otherwise why would they exist?

Comment: you can check for `.isSheetHidden()` and if it is, don't copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => !.isSheetHidden()).map(function(sheet) {
  var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
  var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
  src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
  return dstSheet;
});
```

`sheet.isSheetHidden()` will return `true` if the sheet is hidden, and `false` otherwise. We first filter the list to non-hidden sheets, and then only copy the rest of the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy unhidden sheets

```
function copyunhidden() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !sh.isSheetHidden()).forEach(s => {
    s.copyTo(ss).setName(s.getName() + "_temp")
  });
}
```